# g-dbus error on start-up. Bluetooth services not working

Tags: bluetooth, dbus

I am running Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS on a machine constructed by Entroware as a dedicated Linux laptop.

This morning when I started up I was greeted by a message that Bluetooth will not work - the 'explanation' was:

> g-dbus-error-quark: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown:
> The name :1.27 was not provided by any .service files (2)

I cannot find any questions relating to a Bluetooth issue, but excuse me if I am missing a point?
Can anyone help?

Comment: Same here but on a T430 ThinkPad and it actually showed no such issue for 2 months or so after installing Xubuntu 20.04 on it.